# Bluetooth.connect() throws NullPointerException in Samsung S3 but it works fine in Samsung S. Please anyone know reason?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am tried to write the bluetooth insecure connection code using

```
 Method m = bleutoothdevice.GetMethod("createInsecureRfComm",

            new Class[]{int.class};
    bluetoothSocket = m.InvokeMethod(,)
```

like that 
but in bluetoothSocket.connect call, when running on S3 it gives Null pointer exception 
but the same code working fine for S2 and Acer Tab ..

Anyone know the reason ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call method "createRfcommSocket"